# minify-maven-plugin Where is cssFinalFile?

Tags: java, maven

Running the plugin as the default setup.  Not minifying js, since I don't need it yet.

Get the message in Maven terminal

```
[INFO] --- minify-maven-plugin:1.7.6:minify (default-minify) @ ac3 ---
[INFO] Starting CSS task:
[INFO] Processing source file [branding.css].
[INFO] Processing source file [custom.css].
[INFO] Processing source file [forms.css].
[INFO] Processing source file [layout.css].
[INFO] Processing source file [style.css].
[INFO] Creating the merged file [style_minified.css].
[INFO] Creating the minified file [style_minified.min.css].
[INFO] Uncompressed size: 116427 bytes.
[INFO] Compressed size: 88816 bytes minified (15739 bytes gzipped).
```

But I can't find the file anywhere.  Where does the plugin default to putting `style_minified.min.css` ?

This is my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
    <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>default-minify</id>
             <phase>package</phase><!-- When omitted defaults to 'process-resources' -->
             <configuration>
                   <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                   <cssSourceDir>public/css</cssSourceDir>
                   <cssSourceFiles>
                       <cssSourceFile>branding.css</cssSourceFile>
                       <cssSourceFile>custom.css</cssSourceFile>
                       <cssSourceFile>forms.css</cssSourceFile>
                       <cssSourceFile>layout.css</cssSourceFile>
                       <cssSourceFile>style.css</cssSourceFile>
                   </cssSourceFiles>
                   <cssTargetDir>public/css</cssTargetDir>
                <cssFinalFile>style_minified.css</cssFinalFile>
             </configuration>
             <goals>
                 <goal>minify</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

my other maven processes have this path

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ ac3 ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [ac3] in [/root/dev/workspace/AC3/target/ac3]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/root/dev/workspace/AC3/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [830 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /root/dev/workspace/AC3/target/ac3.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
```

My css path from root:

```
/src/main/webapp/public/css
```

Comment: Your current directory for the .css files is what? Could you share the complete path.

Comment: @nullpointer I've added the path I have for other maven plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is generated under the `target` folder. The complete path being -

```
target/<moduleName>-<moduleVersion>/<cssSourceDirSpecified>
```

> e.g. target/minifyCss-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT/public/style_minified.css

Attaching a sample screenshot from my module named `minifyCss` (which is versioned `2.0.1`) and its directory. Just to clarify, I kept all my resources(basically .css) that were under test with the plugin into the `webapp/public` folder.

[image]